# Checkout from svn into a different directory structure

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have the following directory structure in the svn repository

```
Parent Directory/  
    - BranchFolder1/  
        * Stuff for BranchFolder1/  
    - BranchFolder2/  
        * Stuff for BranchFolder2/  
    - BranchFolder3/  
        * Stuff for BranchFolder3/
```

On disk I want to have this structure:

```
Parent Directory/   
    - Stuff for BranchFolder1/
```

If I cd into the Parent Directory and do an svn update there, it checks out all the branches and their respective contents, which I dont want. How can I get it to only check out/update stuff from inside one of the branches?

Comment: Is this what you want?: `svn checkout "http://path/to/Parent Directory/BranchFolder1" "Stuff for BranchFolder1"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **sparse checkout** feature (available since SVN 1.5):

```
svn checkout --depth empty "http://path/to/Parent Directory
svn up BranchFolder1/
```

The first command will set the working copy depth to empty, so you have only this directory. By issuing the second command Subversion will update only BranchFolder1 to workingCopy depth "infinity". All other directories will stay the same for subsequently used

```
svn up .
```